# Same model for login and register

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have bellow model for a simple login and register page.

Can I use same model for more than one action results??
Because in my register action method the ModelState.isValid = true and in the login action is false...

```
    public int PacientID { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([\+\-_\.][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)+@(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})$", ErrorMessage = "Please provide valid email")]
    public string PacientEmail { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide username", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string PacientUsername { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Password must be 8 char long.")]
    public string PacientPassword { get; set; }

    [Compare("PacientPassword", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password dose not match.")]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes I don't see why you couldn't do that

Comment: of course you can use same model if you want to

Comment: When login, user not need to input the `ConfirmPassword ` ? If yes, login action's `ModelState.isValid` will be false?

Comment: Yes you can. Plus, are saying in the `Register` action *you want* `ModelState.IsValid == true` and in the `Login` action it should be `false` or are you saying that is what is currently happening?

Comment: When you pass the model into the `Login` action are you assigning values to all properties? In particular, when calling `Login` are you assigning a value to `ConfirmPassword` because that property would fail if you assign to `PacientPassword` and not `ConfirmPassword`.

Comment: On login I need only username and password. @MotoSV yes in the register ModelState.IsValid == true and in login is false but I want both to be true?? How can I skip confirm password and email check attributes in login method?

Comment: Create a `Login` model with all the properties apart from `ConfirmPassword`. Then create a `Register` model that derives from the `Login` model and add the `ConfirmPassword` property.

Comment: I'm passing values only for username and password proprieties from my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the properties you require for login into a `LoginModel` and create a `RegisterModel` that derived from `LoginModel` with the extra properties required to register.

For example:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide username", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string PacientUsername { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Password must be 8 char long.")]
    public string PacientPassword { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
    public class YourOriginalClassName
    {
        public int PacientID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide username", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string PacientUsername { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Password must be 8 char long.")]
        public string PacientPassword { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([\+\-_\.][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)+@(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})$", ErrorMessage = "Please provide valid email")]
        public string PacientEmail { get; set; }

        [Compare("PacientPassword", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password dose not match.")]
        [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

UPDATE #1: Following on from your comment that the class in the original post is part of an Entity Framework model, then I would suggest you keep your original class and use that for the `Register` action and create a new `LoginModel` (as shown above) and use that for your `Login` action. One good reason for having a separate `LoginModel` is this class doesn't need to be written to the database and therefore doesn't need to be part of your Entity Framework data model. The downside is the `PacientUsername` and `PacientPassword` properties have to be duplicated along with the validation attributes.

Comment: I get this exception when trying to login or register:An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The entity type RegisterModel is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: Does your original model class represent a database table?

Comment: Well my answer will not work. I would recommend not using your data model classes as models for your view. Instead, have separate models designed specifically for your view, then in your controller action turn those models into a data model instances that can then be written to the database.